# Main doing different tasks on different signals

Tags: c, signals, busy-waiting

So I'm working on a project that I need to have my main do different tasks when it receives a, let's say, `SIGINT` signal and other tasks when it receives a `SIGTSTP`. The rest of the time, main doesn't need to do anything. The code I have come up with until now has a signal handler function for all signals and based on `signo`, it sets the appropriate flag for that signal. Main runs in a `while(1)` loop (with some sleep calls to try to avoid busy waiting) and checks these flags. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Using exponential backoff for sleep time
#define MAX_BACKOFF 3600    // 1 hour
#define INITIAL_BACKOFF 1   // 1 sec

static int backoff = INITIAL_BACKOFF;

static int flgsigint = 0;
static int flgsigtstp = 0;


void sighandler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        flgsigint = 1;
    else if (signo == SIGTSTP)
        flgsigtstp = 1;
    backoff = INITIAL_BACKOFF;
}


int main()
{
    // Handler for SIGINT, SIGTSTP
    static struct sigaction act1;
    act1.sa_handler = sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&(act1.sa_mask));
    sigaddset(&(act1.sa_mask), SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&(act1.sa_mask), SIGTSTP);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act1, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act1, NULL);


    while (1)
    {
        // Using exponential backoff for sleep time

        sleep(backoff);
        backoff = backoff << 2;

        if (backoff > MAX_BACKOFF)
            backoff = MAX_BACKOFF;


        // Check for signal flags

        if (flgsigint) 
        {
            printf("main: gonna do some SIGINT stuff\n");
            // stuff
            flgsigint = 0;
        }

        if (flgsigtstp)
        {
            printf("main: gonna do some SIGTSTP stuff\n");
            // stuff
            flgsigtstp = 0;
        }

    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Now as far as I have tested it, it seems to be working ok. I'm mainly interested in catching the latest of a lets say, burst of `SIGINT`s happening at a specific time, so it doesn't matter if some are lost.

Does my approach seem ok, or will I be surprised by weird behavior as I move on with my project?

Also, is there something better to do about the waiting that main needs to do?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use [`pause`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) to wait for a signal?

Comment: Yes but if the control flow of main is past the check for `flgsigint` and a `SIGINT` comes then it won't see it and `pause` until another signal gets received. Am I right?

Comment: Why not put your `SIGINT stuff' and 'SIGTSTP' stuff in the handler that will be called, and then have a sleep in your while(1)?

Comment: First `pause()`, then check for the flags to see which signal was received. Then go back in the loop to `pause`() again. Unless you have to do other things in the loop as well, then don't `pause()` at all, just have a *small* sleep (or depending on the other things, no sleep at all) and just check the signal flags when needed. And you can just check for failures from other system calls and check if it was `EINTR` in which case there was a signal, and you check your signal flags.

Comment: @CoreyLakey Because stuff involves manipulating different variables and structs declared in main, and I don't know if it would be a good idea to have all of them declared as global so that the handler can access them.

Comment: @DaMike It seems better to separate out of main into its' own module, but without knowing exactly what you're planning on I can't be sure.